# Macro de excel 2003 deja de funcionar de un momento a otro

Tags: excel, vba

como dice el titulo, tengo una macro de excel que ha dejado de funcionar sin motivo aparente, he de decir que esta macro no esta hecha por mi y no he tocado basic en mi vida, la persona que la hizo ya no esta y no puedo preguntarle. Estoy mirando el codigo y buscando el por que ha dejado de funcionar.

La macro en cuestion es:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Option Compare Text

Dim M(), fm&, fechaanterior, fechaposterior, contador1, contador2
Dim R, fr&, fu%, uf&, fila&
Dim Q&, i%, j%, arr
Dim fecha&, DD%, MM%, YY%
Dim GR%, GP%, GF%, GE%, GRC%, GPC%, GFC%, COLUMNA%, QG$, RG
'quite las variables G y GC


Sub OBTENER·NUM·REG()

Dim H As Worksheet
Dim S As Worksheet
fm = 0
fechaanterior = 0
fechaposterior = 0
arr = Array("Gener", "Febrer", "Març", "Abril", "Maig", "Juny", "Juliol", _
             "Agost", "Setembre", "Octubre", "Novembre", "Desembre")


Q = 0
'Por cada hoja de este libro de excel haz'
 For Each H In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets '(GetParcNames)

 'Mientras la hoja del parque x no sea result haz lo siguiente'
   If H.Name <> "Result" Then
      With H
                   'Del rango AA que seria desde el A1 hacia abajo infinito buscame el nombre de hoja
                   '(en este caso parque) que coincida con el nombre de hoja. Normalmente yo tengo en A6
                   'el nombre del parque
    'Si uso MsgBox fu y  MsgBox uf
    'Sale 0 y el mensaje de 7, tanta veces como ficheros hay en el documento, en este caso sale 7 siete veces.
    'Sale 0 y 254 252 249 249 249 249 249
'fu es el resultado de contar todas las hojas'
 'uf es el resultado desde A1 hasta abajo el ultimo nombre
           fu = .Range("A:A").Find(H.Name).Row + 1
           uf = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 'Si uso MsgBox fu y  MsgBox uf
 'Sale 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
 'Sale 254 252 249 249 249 249 249 249

'El primer caso es 0 + (254-7+1*31) = 7688)
'el segundo caso es 7688 + (252-7+1*31)=
            Q = Q + (uf - fu + 1) * 31
            'Aqui puse 12 casos por que son 12 meses
          For i = 1 To 12
            If arr(i) = .Range("a2") Then    'en el rango a2 esta el nombre del mes'
               YY = Year(Now)
               MM = Month(CDate("01/" & i & "/" & YY))
               Exit For
            End If
          Next
      End With
   End If
Next
'aqui cambie 6 + 6 por 7+6 porque son 13 casos. En este caso es 5+6 porque le quite columnas de G y GC
' MsgBox uf si lo uso aqui solo aparece 1 vez 249 y si uso fu sale 7

ReDim M(Q, 5 + 6)
For Each H In Worksheets
   If H.Name <> "Result" Then
      With H
         fu = .Range("A:A").Find(H.Name).Row + 1
         uf = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


         Set R = .Range(.Cells(fu, 1), .Cells(uf, 500))
     'Cuenta de 1 a 248,246,242 de cada hoja
         For fr = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    'Cuenta de 7 a 7 a 254      7 a 252   7 a 249 de cada hoja
            fila = R(fr, 1).Row

            If Len(Trim(R(fr, 1))) > 0 Then


            'Lo ponemos aqui para aseguranos de que cuando llege a 500 los contadores se reinicie a 0
            'y si la fecha es la misma porque pasa al siguiente tio no haya problemas de mesclar
            If (i = 500) Then

                    fechaposterior = 0
                     End If


             'del 6 porque es la priemra celda que comienza la g y el 126 es la antepenultima celda del dia 31
            'step 4 es la cantidad que el bucle aumenta cada vez que pasa
              ' For i = 6 To 126 Step 4
               For i = 6 To 129 Step 1
              '    For j = i To i + 3
              For j = i To i + 3
                     QG = .Cells(fila, j)
                     'Trim() = Saca los espacios de la derecha e izquierda de un string
                     'Len() = devuelve el tamaño de un string  , por jemplo hola 4
                     'si en el campo QG no hay nada pues acaba

                     If Len(Trim(QG)) = 0 Then Exit For



                     Select Case QG
                     'Aqui puse en que columna han de ir cada unos ya que añadi una nueva antes la de categoria

                       ' Case "G":        G = G + 1:  COLUMNA = 5: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For

                        Case "GR":     GR = GR + 1:  COLUMNA = 5: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GP":     GP = GP + 1:  COLUMNA = 6: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GF":     GF = GF + 1:  COLUMNA = 7: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        ' Case "GC":     GC = GC + 1:  COLUMNA = 9: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GE":     GE = GE + 1:  COLUMNA = 8: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GRC":  GRC = GRC + 1: COLUMNA = 9: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GPC":  GPC = GPC + 1: COLUMNA = 10: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For
                        Case "GFC":  GFC = GFC + 1: COLUMNA = 11: GoSub REGISTRAR·DATO: Exit For

                     End Select
                  Next
               Next
            End If

         Next
      End With
   End If
Next

SACAR·DATOS
ORDENAR·DATOS

Exit Sub

REGISTRAR·DATO:

'Stop


'esto ira sumando para k se ponga en la siguiente casilla de result el registro entero
fm = fm + 1
'Con este cogo la primera columna el nombre de cada celda. Em este caso el nombre del empleado
M(fm, 1) = H.Cells(fila, 1)
'Con este cogo la segunda columna en tal caso la categoria que son GRM.
M(fm, 2) = H.Cells(fila, 2)
'Con este cogo el nombre del parque que coincide con el objeto ha h que es cada hoja.
M(fm, 3) = H.Name
'H.cells es hacia abajo y luego hacia la derecha. En este caso es hasta la 4 fila que es 4, y luego la i seria la
'letra por ejemplo , si es 4,2 es fila 4 y columna B osea B4
 'M(fm, 4) = CDbl(CDate(H.Cells(4, i) & "/" & MM & "/" & YY))
 ' MsgBox uf

 'Con estas variables la uso para luego poder comparar la fecha anterior con la nueva y asi saber si sumar 8
fechaanterior = fechaposterior
'43251  699                     130          5        2018
M(fm, 4) = CDbl(CDate(H.Cells(4, i) & "/" & MM & "/" & YY))
fechaposterior = M(fm, 4)


'Con esta condicion haremos que compruebe si las fechas son las mismas o si la letra a buscar es la misma
'asi si no lo es reiniciara el contador para que no salga 16 en lugar de 8 etc..
'Ademas en el momento que detecte que la fecha es diferente reiniciar el contador
'si es la misma pero de diferente tio se reiniciara arriba porqu epasara por los 500 celdas antes de pasar
'al siguiente tio
 If (fechaposterior <> fechaanterior Or QG <> RG) Then
contador2 = 0
RG = QG
End If



'Con esta condicion haremos que si las fechas son las mismas se sumara 8 al numero anterior y lo sustituira
'sino solo pondra 8
If fechaposterior = fechaanterior Then
  'Con este se pone la cifra que aparece
contador2 = contador2 + 8
'Le resto a fm para que en caso de que sume 8 se ponga encima del registro anterior y asi aparezca 16
fm = fm - 1
M(fm, COLUMNA) = contador2
Else
M(fm, COLUMNA) = 8
contador2 = contador2 + 8
End If



Return

sale:
Sheets(H.Name).Select
MsgBox "En general, este error está en la celda A6: el nombre que aquí figura no concuerda con el de la hoja"
Stop
Exit Sub

End Sub
Private Sub SACAR·DATOS()
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Result").Select

'aqui es importante poner 11 porque son 11 columnas sobre las que trabajamos
On Error GoTo 0
Cells.ClearContents
Range("A1").Resize(, 11) = Array("NOM", "CATEGORIA", "PARC", "DATA", "GR", "GP", "GF", "GE", "GRC", "GPC", "GFC")
Range("A1").Resize(, 11).Font.Bold = True

MsgBox "Continuar ..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A2").Resize(fm, 11) = M

Range("A:IV").Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Cells(1, 1).Select

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub


Public Function GetParcNames() As Variant

    GetParcNames = Array("Calvia", "Inca", "Manacor", "Soller", "Alcudia", "Felanitx", "Arta", "Llucmajors                                       ") 'spelling and accents must be same for sheet names and in sheet as are spelt here

End Function



Private Sub ORDENAR·DATOS()
Dim R As Range, fr&, cr%
   Set R = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
Dim Q&
   Q = R.Rows.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & Q), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & Q), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & Q), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:F" & Q)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

For fr = R.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
   If R(fr, 1) & R(fr, 2) = R(fr - 1, 1) & R(fr - 1, 2) Then
      R(fr, 1) = ""
      R(fr, 2) = ""
      fr = fr + 1
   End If
Next

For cr = 4 To R.Columns.Count
   R(1, cr).ColumnWidth = 5
Next

End Sub
```

Esta Macro ha dejado de funcionar despues de que en el documento que se utiliza se le añadieran unas filas de trabajoderes nuevos.

El fallo que me esta dando es:

M(fm, 4) = CDbl(CDate(H.Cells(4, i) & "/" & MM & "/" & YY))

Me dice que no coinciden los tipos.

Necesito hacer que funciona de forma urgente y no encuentro como.

Comment: ¿Has probado a crear la variable `xlSortOnValues`?

Comment: @David no he intentado crearla puesto que el codigo funcionava sin tener que crear esta variable, donde la crearia?

Lo unico que he encontredo es que xlSortOnValues falla en excel 2003, pero ha estado funcionando asta ahora.

Comment: Tu código parece correcto, xlSortOnValues no es ninguna variable @David, es una propiedad que le dice a excel básicamente de ordenar por valores. La verdad es Iván que sin el archivo para probarlo costaría mucho encontrar dónde está el fallo. Si puedes adjuntar el archivo con datos (inventados) sería más fácil. También puede que hayáis cambiado la versión de Office y eso esté afectando, el añadido de trabajadores no debería afectar ya que lo tiene en cuenta.

Comment: @Damian he provado con una version de excel más nueva 2016 y la macro funciona, no entiendo por que ha dejado de funcionar en el excel 2003.

Comment: @IvánMontero haz una cosa, coge y ejecuta la macro, cuando te dé el error la paras y te vas a grabar una macro y ordenas tú los datos. Entonces coges el código que te de y lo puedes modificar para ajustarlo ahí. El tema es que `SortOn` no funciona en el 2003.

Comment: @Damian provando la Macro me ha dado un fallo de que no coinciden los tipos en:
M(fm, 4) = CDbl(CDate(H.Cells(4, i) & "/" & MM & "/" & YY))
No se como adjuntar una plantilla en este foro.

Comment: Sigo sin conseguir que la macro funcione.